# Is there a trick to resizing a panel and video for playback

Tags: .net, c++-cli, directx-9, audiovideoplayback

I am using directx.audiovideoplayback to play an avi and I want to have it size the video to 320x240 (it's actual size is 1260x876) but when I do what it appears I should do this does not happen. I also tried attaching an event handler for the TextureReadyToRender event but that does not seem to fire when playing the video. The documentation at Microsoft is less than helpful.

I set video and panel sizes accordingly and attached an event handler as prescribed.

```
#pragma once
#include "metahost.h"

namespace PlaAVIviaDirectX {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace Microsoft::DirectX::AudioVideoPlayback;
using namespace System::Configuration;

/// <summary>
/// Summary for Form1
/// </summary>
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    Form1(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
        System::Drawing::Size vSize = System::Drawing::Size(320,240);
        panel1->Width = 320;
        panel1->Height = 240;
        video = gcnew Microsoft::DirectX::AudioVideoPlayback::Video("D:\\SS-RICS Eric Stuff\\intro.avi");
        video->TextureReadyToRender += gcnew Microsoft::DirectX::AudioVideoPlayback::TextureRenderEventHandler(this, &Form1::FrameHandler);
        video->DefaultSize = vSize;
        video->Owner = panel1;
        //video->TextureReadyToRender += gcnew Microsoft::DirectX::AudioVideoPlayback::TextureRenderEventHandler(this, &Form1::FrameHandler);
    }

protected:
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    ~Form1()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
private: Microsoft::DirectX::AudioVideoPlayback::Video^ video;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Panel^  panel1;
protected: 
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button2;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button3;

private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        this->panel1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Panel());
        this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // panel1
        // 
        this->panel1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 12);
        this->panel1->Name = L"panel1";
        this->panel1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(320, 240);
        this->panel1->TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 314);
        this->button1->Name = L"button1";
        this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
        this->button1->TabIndex = 1;
        this->button1->Text = L"play";
        this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button1_Click);
        // 
        // button2
        // 
        this->button2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 343);
        this->button2->Name = L"button2";
        this->button2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
        this->button2->TabIndex = 2;
        this->button2->Text = L"pause";
        this->button2->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->button2->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button2_Click);
        // 
        // button3
        // 
        this->button3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 372);
        this->button3->Name = L"button3";
        this->button3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
        this->button3->TabIndex = 3;
        this->button3->Text = L"stop";
        this->button3->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->button3->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button3_Click);
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(347, 407);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button3);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button2);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->panel1);
        this->Name = L"Form1";
        this->Text = L"Form1";
        this->ResumeLayout(false);

    }
#pragma endregion
private: void FrameHandler(Object^ sender, Microsoft::DirectX::AudioVideoPlayback::TextureRenderEventArgs^ e)
         {
             Microsoft::DirectX::Direct3D::Texture^ frame = e->Texture;
             System::Diagnostics::Trace::WriteLine("texture");
         }
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             video->Play();
         }
private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             video->Pause();
         }
private: System::Void button3_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         video->Stop();
     }
};
}
```

I expected to see an commensurately sized video and output showing that the event handler was working.

Comment: Please ignore the line:

        video->DefaultSize = vSize;

in the constructor. It was an attempt to set a value that was read only and has been deleted. I did not know how to edit the code section.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is the size member (read/write) :

[Video.Size Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/bb281572(v%3Dvs.85))